# Asp.net mvc5:kendo grid ui add a new object instead if editing an object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm using the telerik component of kendo grid ui, I'm following demos in the official site but I have an issue. When I create a new object A and then edit that object A, another one is created in the database. The `CreateAgency` action is invoked not the `UpdateAgency`. What does it mean? What should I do to fix this issue? 
Here is my `CreateAgency` and `UpdateAgency` actions
 `

```
//Create Agency
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult CreateAgency([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest dsRequest, [Bind(Include = "Id,Code,Name,Email,Fax,Tel,TradeRegisterNumber,CompanyId")] AgenceViewModel Agency)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Agency Agencytoadd;
                Agencytoadd = new Agency { Name = Agency.Name, Code = Agency.Code, Email = Agency.Email, Fax = Agency.Fax, Tel = Agency.Tel, TradeRegisterNumber = Agency.TradeRegisterNumber};
                Agencytoadd.Company = db.Companies.Find(Agency.CompanyId);
                db.Agencies.Add(Agencytoadd);
                db.SaveChanges();
                // Get the Id of inserted element
                long id = Agencytoadd.Id;
                // pass the Id of inserted element to CompanyViewModels

            }
            return Json(new[] { Agency }.ToDataSourceResult(dsRequest, ModelState));
        }

        // Update Agency
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult UpdateAgency([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest dsRequest, [Bind(Include = "Id,Code,Name,Email,Fax,Tel,TradeRegisterNumber,CompanyId")] AgenceViewModel Agency)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Agency Agencytoupdated = db.Agencies.Find(Agency.Id);

                Agencytoupdated.Code = Agency.Code;
                Agencytoupdated.Name = Agency.Name;
                Agencytoupdated.Email = Agency.Email;
                Agencytoupdated.Fax = Agency.Fax;
                Agencytoupdated.Tel = Agency.Tel;
                Agencytoupdated.TradeRegisterNumber = Agency.TradeRegisterNumber;
                Agencytoupdated.Company = db.Companies.Find(Agency.CompanyId);

                db.Entry(Agencytoupdated).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            //return Json(ModelState.ToDataSourceResult());
            return Json(new[] { Agency }.ToDataSourceResult(dsRequest, ModelState));
        }
`
```

Comment: Post your view. How do you invoke create and update actions?

Comment: @ michael moore i follow the demos:i puted:  .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource 
      .Ajax() 
      .Read(read => read.Action("UpdateAgency", "Agency"))      .Create(Create => Create.Action("CreateAgency", "Agency"))
   )

Comment: Read should call controller method that returns data. UpdateAgency method should be called in Update handler => (...).Update(read => read.Action("UpdateAgency", "Agency"))(...)

Comment: @kul_mi i didn't understand you could you give me an example please

Answer (score 0):

As @kul_mi already suggested, your `Read` should point to action that returns data to show in the grid. You're either missing that action or didn't post it. As for how to properly configure your Kendo UI Grid, you should have something like this

```
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .Read(r => r.Action("YourActionNameThatReturnsData", "ControllerName")
            .Update(u => u.Action("UpdateAgency", "Agency")
            .Create(c => c.Action("CreateAgency", "Agency")
```